# How do you describe someone who is always open to propositions?

Tags: word-request, adjectives

My girlfriend is an amazing person that is always OK with any suggestion: she would be pleased by any place I prpose to visit, any idea of movies. She likes all kind of music, or all genre of movies. Her answer to "In what restaurant do you want to eat?" is invariably "Anything is fine to me."

It is not that she has no opinion or judgement. She will tell you (without complaining) if she disliked a movie, or something. She also can stand on her political and philosophical position. When things are set down, she will enthusiastically and dynamically participate. It is not like she has no taste and is just a follower, but more that she loves so many things that she cannot decide and any proposition would fit her.

How would you call such a person?

My thought so far:

- *Open minded* does not seem to apply since an open-minded person is someone that accepts other people's opinion. She is open-minded when it comes to try new things but it doesn't fully describe her behavior.
- She's definitely *undecided* but I would like something that depicts her positive mood.
- Not sure if *easygoing* applies here.
- She is of course not an *easy girl* ^^

Comment: Does she speak English? Have you asked her?

Comment: Yes, she does. But, I am asking here because I think I would have a better answer. She would describe herself as undecided, in a quite negative way :(

Comment: i think easygoing does work. this is precisely what easygoing means to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- She is "accommodating".  She is eager to fit in with whatever you suggest.  http://www.google.com/search?q=obliging&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#hl=en&q=accommodating
- She is "affable". That is, she tries to get along and not make a fuss over anything. Opposites might include "argumentative", "contrary", "difficult"  (no matter what you suggest, she suggests something else, as if she were being opposite just to be opposite)
- She is "amenable". This is similar to "open"; she can accept any idea or plan.  (often "open to _____" or "amenable to _____") http://www.google.com/search?q=obliging&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&hl=en&q=amenable
- She is  "complaisant" (not to be confused with "complacent")  http://www.google.com/search?q=obliging&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&hl=en&q=complaisant
- She is "deferential". That is, she accepts your wishes or judgment—to be polite (out of respect for you). Opposite might be "overbearing" (imposing her decision on you, regardless what you think.)
- She is "flexible".  She can adapt to any situation. Perhaps she really doesn't care. Opposite is "rigid" (with very specific, unchangeable ideas of what she wants or would agree to)
- She is "obliging". That is, she wishes to please you by doing what you want to do. http://www.google.com/search?q=obliging&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en
- She is "pliant" (easily persuaded or influenced)  http://i.word.com/idictionary/pliant
- She is "tractable" http://www.google.com/search?q=obliging&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&hl=en&q=tractable

Answer (score 2):

There's an adjective that means having this attitude of willingness to participate right at the moment:

> I'm **[game](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/game#Adjective)**.

To speak of it as a character trait, I've heard "She's always **game**" or "She's **game** for anything." It indicates a zestful willingness to dive in to new things, not a lack of judgement.

---

By the way, you might take a look at [this recommendation to get a thesaurus](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/51667/6700). "Game" in this sense appears Roget's Thesaurus, §622 "Willingness", along with many similar adjectives: *willing, willinghearted, alacritous, amenable, ready and willing, well-disposed,* and many more.

Comment: I think *game* fits with her. *Well-disposed for everything* too.